# Necesito cargar un menu de la base de datos en la vista de mi proyecto .net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Tengo una tabla `menu` en Sql Server y estoy intentado hacer una función recursiva que me cargue el menú con todos sus hijos, actualmente mi tabla `menu` tiene lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Donde `ParentID` tiene el `id` del padre al que corresponde ese hijo, lo que necesito es poder obtener este menú en una lista para poder recorrerla en la vista y mostrar ese menú.

Supongamos que tenemos una lista de Menu que representa el listado de todo lo que hay en la base de datos.

```
public void ObtenerMenu(List<Menu> lista)
{
     for (int i=0; i<lista.Count; i++)
     {

      }
}
```

Comment: o sea vos queres un select? que intentaste hasta ahora.. igual por codigo o usando linq parece mucho mas facil de resolver...

Comment: traigo los datos del sql perfecto, mi problema radica en la recursividad, me haria falta una funcion para eso.

Comment: no escribas el codigo en un comentario. usa [edit] y agregalo a la pregunta

Comment: ok ahora explica como quedo.. porque eso es mucho codigo y no sabemos donde puede fallar exactamente.. y no necesitas recursividad.. o tenes hijos de los hijos?

Comment: por el momento no tengo hijos de los hijos pero mas adelante tendre un menu que si tendra hijos de hijos o quizas mas, en el codido lo que trato de hacer es crear una lista de menu aunque hay mas cosas alli pues he probado de todo, pero la idea es retornar una lista de menu

Comment: ok.. ponele que retornas una lista.. donde esta fallando?

Comment: mira el codigo no da error, o sea no falla, me devuelve una lista pero no con lo que tiene que darme, me explico, al final me da la lista con valores repetidos, modifique el codigo y ahora me retorna la lista vacia, porfa ayudame con eso, es que no acabo de entender la recursividad

Comment: Si haces un [mcve] que podamos usar para refactorizar tu codigo tal vez podamos ayudarte